# Bringing Variables from one form to another

Tags: c#

I want to bring variables (Amount and Interest rates) made in Form 1 into Form 3.
I need to put the variables made in form 1 into labels in form 3 or get the variables from form 1 into form 3. Is there any way to pass variables from one form to another and how?

```
namespace InvestmentCalc
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    decimal Amount;
    decimal WeekInterest;
    decimal TwoWeekInterest;
    decimal MonthInterest;
    decimal ThreeMonthInterest;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ParseItems();
        Formchange();
    }
        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void ClearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    //Methods

        public void ParseItems()
        {
            WeekInterest = decimal.Parse(WeekIntTextBox.Text);
            TwoWeekInterest = decimal.Parse(tWeekIntTextBox.Text);
            MonthInterest = decimal.Parse(monthIntTextBox.Text);
            ThreeMonthInterest = decimal.Parse(threeMonthIntTextBox.Text);
            Amount = decimal.Parse(DepositTextBox1.Text);
        }

        public void Formchange()
        {
            Form3 Check = new Form3();
            Check.Show();
            Hide();
        }                                                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly, but you would have to look for a solution at a higher level. First, instantiate the first form, then e.g. show it modal, when the call returns, read the properties from that form and pass them to the next one.

```cs
int amount, interest;
using (Form1 form = new Form1()) 
{
    form.ShowDialog();
    amount = form.Amount;     // these, of course, have to be public
    interest = form.Interest; // make the fields private and expose them via properties
    [...]
}

using (Form2 form = new Form2(amount, interest))
{
    form.ShowDialog();
}
```

`ShowDialog()` returns when the form closes, so it's probably the easiest thing to do here.

Depending on how many values you need to pass, creating a struct or class to hand them over might be a good strategy.

[Edit:] In contrast to the other answer, this will spawn a series of forms. Passing the current form into the constructor of a new one, although not necessarily, is more of a modal-dialog approach. If that was indeed what you were asking for, all you need to know is that you can write a form with a constructor that requires arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to pass variables from one form to another and how? Thanks

Sure, simplest way is define your variables as `public`.Then when you opening your second form pass your current `Form` instance to `Show` method:

```
Form3 f3 = new Form3();
f3.Show(this);
```

Then inside of `Form3` cast `Owner` to your `Form1` and access your variable like this

```
((Form1)Owner).VariableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move many value to another form, create constructor first in form3(in here for example sent two string from form1 to form3)

```
Public Form3(object[] data) :this()
{
string s1 = data[0].Tostring();
string s2 = data[1].Tostring();
label1.Text = s1;
label2.Text = s2;
}
```

in form1, now we can create form3 that can receive our data, stringA will be sent to form3 as s1, stringB will be sent to form3 as s2.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
stringA = "my value";
stringB = "my another value";
object[] data = {stringA, stringB};
Form3 frm = new Form3(data);
frm.Showdialog();
}
```